# Custom Post Taxonomy Template Not Loading Properly

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, theme-development, templates

I have a website I inherited that is exhibiting strange behavior for a custom post type taxonomy template.

The post type is `resource`, the taxonomy is `resource_brand`, and if it matters, the taxonomy is rewritten as `brand`.

I have a template for brands at `taxonomy-resource_brand.php` that is NOT being called when I view the taxonomy archive at `/brand/{brand}`. Instead, a template called `taxonomy-resource.php` is loaded, which is not even a registered taxonomy on the site. If I delete this file, the website crashes when it tries to load the taxonomy archive.

How can I troubleshoot this effectively? I've tried disabling the rewrite, and double/triple checking the template files before coming here.

Comment: Deleting a template file would not cause a website to crash, it would just fall back to the next template in the hierarchy. This suggests you have code that's manually causing taxonomy-resource.php to load, which is failing when it can't find it. Have you attempted to filter the templates at any stage?

Comment: Thank you, @JacobPeattie, there is a filter on ```template_include```. Disabling it opened a new avenue I can continue debugging on.

Comment: You shouldn't need template_include for post type or taxonomy archive templates.

Comment: This is an inherited site, some stuff on it is weird. Hopefully, I can refactor it to make more sense!